# Access map data by using groovy

Tags: groovy

This is my code.

```
def map = ['test.key.one': 'value1', 'test2.key2': 'value2']
def props = new Properties()
props.putAll(map)
println new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)   //[test:[key:[one:value1]], test2:[key2:value2]]
println(map['test2'])
```

Result of `println(map['test2'])` is `null` but I expect `[key2:value2]`. Cloud you please help me?

Comment: Would you mind showing your data instead of map? Because, not sure why you are using `ConfigSlurper` as data is already in map, there is no point in converting to properties and ConfigSlurper. Accessing map should be quite simple.

Comment: `null` is correct result as there is no `test2` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `null` when you access `map['test2']` because the code you have shown us does not modify `map` variable. If you expect to see

```
[key2: value2]
```

after accessing key `test2` then you have to assign result of

```
new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)
```

to a value and then access `test2` key on that newly created variable, e.g.

```
def map = ['test.key.one': 'value1', 'test2.key2': 'value2']
def props = new Properties()
props.putAll(map)
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)

assert config['test2'] == [key2: 'value2']
```